# How to send collection to Postman

Tags: java, collections, postman

My controller is

```
@PostMapping(value = V1,
             consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
             produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)

public ResponseEntity includeParameters(@PathVariable UUID id,
                                        @RequestBody Set<UUID> parameters) throws InventoryListException {

   log.debug("Отправление команды добавления параметров к списку инвентаризации с ID " + id);
   service.includeParameters(id, parameters);
   return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I wanted to test it through postman but having some issues.

how to send collection of UUID to Postman ?

Comment: Is this your correct postMapping path value? then why PathVariable ?

Comment: Inside PathVariable is ID of one entity and besides it, i need to get the Set<UUID>

Comment: it should be something like V1/{id} right?

Comment: V1 variable  has that attribute